# Unable to convert simple "yyyy:MM:dd HH:mm:ss" to date object. any solution

Tags: ios, swift, date

My device date is perfectly fine.

```
let DateString = "2021-07-09 03:00:00"
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"
    let myDate = dateFormatter.date(from: DateString)
```

//  result I get =  myDate = 2021-07-08 22:00:00 +0000

//  Expected result =  myDate = 2021-07-09 03:00:00

I know this question may be replied thousand time on stack but believe me I have tried almost every solution still unable to convert a simple string into date.

Comment: I don't know if it is required but I feel I should mention my current time zone Asia/Karachi.

Comment: Unless you specify otherwise date formatter takes into account your timezone and remove it to get a UTC date. The result is correct.

Comment: You have an output "problem", not a conversion problem (You don't have a problem at all really, just confusion).  A `Date` is a point in time.  When you print a `Date` without using a date formatter (and this includes examining it in the debugger) it is shown in UTC (+0), not +5.  If you print `myDate.description(with: Locale.autoupdatingCurrent)` what do you get?

Comment: Yes I got it @Paulw11 thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not having any problem. You *did* convert the string into a date, correctly. 2021-07-08 22:00:00 +0000 (London time zone) is exactly the same thing as 2021-07-09 03:00:00 in your time zone (Karachi). Everything is fine. You are getting exactly the right result.

Comment: But thing this function was supposed to return me same date like string I pass

Comment: Well stop thinking that and think about what I said. What you've created is a date, not a string, and I've just proved to you that it's the right date. Don't worry be happy.

Comment: just convert that date into string you will get as you want hassan.

Comment: how I'll get DateObject with same date I pass in string. 
StringDate =  "2021-07-09 03:00:00". DateIwant = "2021-07-09 03:00:00"

Comment: Watch my lips. "You have the date you want." It isn't being written in the time zone you like, but that's because you didn't say how you wanted it written. But it's the exact right date.

Comment: var S : String  = "1"
var myInt = Int( String : S)
// myInt = 1 right ?

why not Date is exactly same as  2021-07-09 03:00:00

Comment: `let x = 0x20; print(x)` - The output is 32. Why? Because it is printed in decimal, not hexadecimal but it is the same value.  You have parsed a date in your Timezone (because "2021-07-09 03:00:00" is interpreted  as "2021-07-09 03:00:00 +05:00" due to your Timezone being associated with the date formatter) but printed it in UTC - It is the same date

Comment: I got your point guys. Thank you so much! It was just confusion.